# Error trying to run GCCG while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, shared-library

I'm trying to run GCCG (a multiplatform implementation of a card game engine) on my Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64, but I always get the following error:

```
./ccg_client: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Of course I thought the library was missed and I tried to install using apt-get, but I realized it was already installed.

When i use

```
$ locate -i libjpeg
```

this is what i get:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjpeg.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg-turbo8
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg62
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg8
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg-turbo8/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg-turbo8/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg62/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg62/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg62/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg8/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg8/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libjpeg-turbo8
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg-turbo8:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg-turbo8:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg-turbo8:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg-turbo8:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg-turbo8:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg-turbo8:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg-turbo8:i386.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg-turbo8:i386.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg-turbo8:i386.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg-turbo8:i386.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg-turbo8:i386.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg-turbo8:i386.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg62:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg62:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg62:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg62:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg8:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg8:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg8:i386.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libjpeg8:i386.md5sums
```

Any idea of what is going bad?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the executable you are trying to run a 32 bit executable, by any chance?

The `locate` output shows you have a 64-bit version of `libjpeg.so.62` (in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`), but that can't be used if the executable is 32-bit.

You can determine what architecture a file is compiled for using the `file` command.  For instance:

```
$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x214a38d0db472db559f0dabf0ae97f82fea83e03, stripped
```

If it says you have a 32-bit executable, then that is your problem.

You can install the 32-bit version of the library in question using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386
```

Comment: Thanks A lot @James Henstridge, indeed the file was a 32 bit executable, but installing the libjpeg62:i386 worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

```
cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libjpeg.so.8.0.2 libjpeg.so.62
```

Now you will solve the problem

Comment: This is really bad advice.  The two libraries are not binary compatible (have different sonames), so you risk causing segfaults by doing this.